# Chef creating a comma separated string from template and knife search

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to create a dynamically created comma separated list of Splunk indexers (with the data port appended to each host name) from a knife query that supplies the returned list of hosts to a template and corresponding erb.

However the string in the conf file never gets created although no errors are thrown when I converge on my test Docker instance.

Here's the knife query, the attribute it's referencing, and the template resource

```
attribute file entry:
default['forwarder']['indexer_role'] = 'splunk_indexer'


knife query and template resource:
indexers = search(:node, "role:#{node['forwarder']['indexer_role']}")

template '/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/outputs.conf' do
  source "system_local_outputs.erb"
  owner 'nobody'
  group 'nobody'
  mode 0600
  action :create
  variables(
    :indexers  => indexers
  )
end
```

And this is the corresponding erb file for that template resource

```
[tcpout]
defaultGroup = default-autolb-group

[tcpout:default-autolb-group]
disabled = false
<% @indexers.each do |member| %>
  server = <%= member[ :hostname]  + ":5501," %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know if the query is specified incorrectly, or whether the template resource is wrong or if I've made a mistake in the erb code.

As I mentioned above there are no errors thrown, the code compiles and converges without any error messages.  The line is simply not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wouldn't create a comma-separated list, it would make multiple lines like:

```
server = foo:5501,
server = bar:5501,
```

What you probably want in the template is more like this:

```
server = <%= @indexers.map {|n| "#{n}:5501" }.join(",") %>
```

However if you don't see those lines in the first place, it is likely your search query isn't working. Try checking it with `knife search` and probably use `roles:` instead of `role:` as it is more often correct.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct about the erb not making a comma separate list.  

 I checked the query and `knife search 'roles:splunk_indexer'` does work correctly.

I should clarify that part of the line exists "server ="  but that line does not contain a new line so I missed it earlier.  Still the query doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm running this in test-kitchen.  So I realized that test-kitchen doesn't query the server and that's why the query isn't returning anything.  So I accepted your answer because it lead me to realize this.  Thanks for the help.