# Testing Chef search queries in recipes using Test Kitchen

Tags: chef-infra

In a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44855196/3481957) I asked about creating a comma separated list of hosts from a Chef query.  The problem though is that I'm using test-kitchen which doesn't use the Chef server so that was why my query was not returning any hosts.

My question is then, how do you test recipes that rely on Chef queries in test kitchen? Preloading data into a file or something along those lines won't expose any bugs in the knife query itself.  Is there a busser that would allow me to run queries against the Chef Server?

Update: Below is the code to support the strange results I'm getting from the Chef query.

Recipe:

```
# Create output conf file
indexers = search("node", "role:#{node['forwarder']['indexer_role']}")

template '/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/outputs.conf' do
  source "system_local_outputs.erb"
  owner 'nobody'
  group 'nobody'
  mode 0600
  action :create
variables(
  :indexers  => indexers
)
end
```

Template ERB

```
[tcpout]
defaultGroup = default-autolb-group

[tcpout:default-autolb-group]
disabled = false
server = <%= @indexers.map {|n| "#{n}:5501" }.join(",") %>
```

attributes/default.rb

```
default['forwarder']['indexer_role'] = 'splunk_indexer'
```

Command line query inside Docker instance to test if forwarders are configured correctly

```
sudo /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk list forward-server -auth admin:<password>

Active forwards:
None
Configured but inactive forwards:
node[splunk-001-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-002-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-003-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-004-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-005-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-006-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-007-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-008-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-009-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-010-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-011-indexer.example.com]:5501
node[splunk-012-indexer.example.com]:5501
```

Finally, the contents of outputs.conf file

```
sudo cat /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/outputs.conf
[tcpout]
defaultGroup = default-autolb-group

[tcpout:default-autolb-group]
disabled = false
server = node[dspe-splunk-001-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-002.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-003-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-004-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-005-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-006-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-007-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-008.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-009-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-010-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-011-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501,node[dspe-splunk-012-indexer.pbp.gq1.yahoo.com]:5501
```

Comment: Those are not "knife queries", that's just a search in Chef. `knife` is just the interface to it on the workstation.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I've corrected that, thanks.  Muscle memory habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock search data (for nodes) by putting JSON files below `test/integration/nodes/`:

An [example file](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/backuppc/blob/af387193aa19dfa3460f2783efb2310625884273/test/integration/nodes/testhost.json) looks as follows:

```
{
  "id":       "testhost",
  "name":     "testhost.example.com",
  "chef_type": "node",
  "json_class": "Chef::Node",
  "run_list": [],
  "chef_environment": "production",
  "automatic": {
    "fqdn": "testhost.example.com",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, I'm aware of that method.  But I'm then not really testing the code like it would be executed in a production environment, correct?  Shouldn't there be some way of making calls to the Chef Server from inside of Test Kitchen?

Comment: Actually, this data is picked up by Chef solo/zero (the server part) and chef-client makes the calls to this API. With test-kitchen, you don't test against your "real" Chef Server.

Comment: Sure, that's the idea. You mock the data how you expect it in production.

Comment: I created a file like you demonstrate above in test but the results seem strange compared to the results when the same query is used with knife in a production environment

`Configured but inactive forwards:
        node[splunk-001-indexer.example.com]:8888`

The outputs.conf file contains an entry like that but I'm confused as to why `node[]` is being included as the results of the query.

Comment: Code or it did not happen.

Comment: You provably want to access `node['fqdn']`.

Comment: Oh yes, that's probably the reason why.

Comment: Actually I needed to add that to my template ERB as it turns out `server = <%= @indexers.map {|indexer| "#{indexer['fqdn']}:5501" }.join(",") %>`

Otherwise if I added it to the query I got a "Not a URI" error.  It now works perfectly.

Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Fauxhai turns out to provide the ability to gather data from the Chef server instead of mocking the data up.  I just stumbled across this [entry](https://github.com/chefspec/fauxhai#fetching):

> Alternatively, if you do not want to mock the data, Fauxhai provides a fetch mechanism for collecting "real" Ohai data from a remote server or local file. Maybe you want to test against the fully-replicated environment for a front-facing server in your pool. Just pass in the url option instead of a platform:
>
> The fetch method supports all the same options as the Net-SSH command, such as :user, :password, :key_file, etc.
>
> The fetch method will cache the JSON file in a temporary path on your local machine. Similar to gems like VCR, this allows Fauxhai to use the cached copy, making your test suite run faster. You can optionally force a cache miss by passing the :force_cache_miss => true option to the fetch initializer. Because this is real data, there may be a security concern. Secure your laptop accordingly.